# List<> in Gridview upon startup creates columns, but Dictionary<> doesn't. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, gridview, dictionary

When setting a List<> as a the itemssource of a Gridview(WPF), columns are created when the application starts.

See sample code with List as itemssource. This correctly generates the columns: "File", "Duration" and "Status" when running the program without any objects being added to the list.

```
 public MainWindow()
         {
          InitializeComponent();
          DataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadFiles();
         }

 public class Files
        {
            public string File { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }

        List<Files> files = new List<Files>();

        private List<Files> LoadFiles()
        { 
            return files;
        }
```

Now I rewrote the code to bind the GridView with a Dictionary type instead, as I needed to store value/key pairs. But upon application being loaded, columns are not generated. The columns are only generated after the Dictionary get populated with content:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = LoadFile();   
    }
 public class Files
        {
            public string File { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }  
        }

Dictionary<Files, string> files = new Dictionary<Files, string>();

        private Dictionary<Files, string> LoadFiles()
        {
            return files;
        }
```

I would like to have the columns created even when Dictionary<> is empty. Any advice?

Comment: Using the Dictionary, and changing LoadFiles() to return a List<Files> y finally returns files.Keys.ToList<Files>() ?  you could put the XAML code of DataGrid?

Comment: In upper block of code you have nothing UN-initialized. But in lower one, you are initializing Dictionary but it does initialize neither Files nor string(). So I think you can only generate columns by adding 1 value for files and string before load. You can remove it when you are going to add the actual values